# Unable to join non-related or non-association tables together using symfony doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to join the two tables based on a reference key but getting the following error

Error:
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 85 near 'event_id = e.id': Error: Class AppBundle\Entity\EventLocation has no field or association named event_id

Below is the query

```
$qb = $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('e')
        ->select('e')            
        ->innerJoin('AppBundle:EventLocation', 'el', 'WITH', 'el.event_id = e.id')            
        ->where('e.event_id = :event_id')    
        ->setParameter('event_id', $eventId);
```

EventLocation Entity

```
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="event_id", type="integer")
    */
private $eventId;
```

Comment: I think the error message is clear and it looks like you don't have an association declared in your entity.

Comment: @shaNnex. I didn't set the relationship set in the entity. Is it necessary to set the mapping in order to join query?

Comment: Can you show us your EventLocation entity, especially where the event_id is on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yous should have a look of associations in doctrine http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

To join entities in doctrine you need an Association

```
<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping AS ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Event
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="EventLocation", mappedBy="event")
     */
    private $eventLocation;
}
```

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class EventLocation
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="event_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Event", inversedBy="eventLocation")
     */
    private $event;
}
```

Comment: Yes. I did that